# How do i print something on focusOut on TextField in javafx2

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, java, java-7, javafx-8

I have a TextField and want to perform some action on textfiels focus out

```
TextField textField = new TextField();
```

how do i print

```
System.ou.prinln("Focus Out");
```

When focus out from textfield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JavaFX 2.2` [TextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html) has a **public** [focusedProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#focusedProperty) inherited from the [Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) class, just add a [ChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html) and implement the [changed](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html#changed%28javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue,%20T,%20T%29) method.

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField txt1= new TextField("text 1");
        TextField txt2= new TextField("text 2 ");
        Button btn= new Button("hello");

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        VBox vBox= VBoxBuilder.create()
                .children(txt1, btn, txt2)
                .build();

        txt1.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
                if (t1) {
                    System.ou.prinln("Focus In");
                } else {
                    System.ou.prinln("Focus Out");
                }

            }
        });

        root.getChildren().add(vBox);       
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 400);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
     * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
     * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
     * support. NetBeans ignores main().
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```